# pymunk updated shape filter usage

Tags: python, filter, shapes, segment, pymunk

I am trying to detect the first shape along a segment starting at my player's position, but I do not want to detect the player.

In a previous version of pymunk, the pymunk.Space.segment_query_first function accepted an integer as the shape_filter and it only detected shapes within a group of that integer. That worked perfectly, but now it accepts a list or dictionary instead. I have tried putting the integer into a list and that didn't work. I have no idea what it wants with a dictionary. I have tried everything that I can think of. Nothing seems to stop it from detecting my player. The documentation is not helpful at all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured it outshape.filter = [int]

Comment: I accidentally posted that last comment and I cant seem to delete it :/         I figured it out, i just set player_shape.filter to [1] and passed [1] to the shape_filter argument. If there are any common numbers between the two lists, it seems to ignore the collision. If anyone wants to explain how to use a dictionary here instead of a list, I'm still interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the shape filter have become more powerful in pymunk 5 (and as a result also a little bit more complicated). The shape filter is supposed to be a `ShapeFilter` object (but . See the api docs http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.ShapeFilter for details on this filter object.

The `ShapeFilter` has 3 properties: `categories`, `mask`, and `group`. In your case I think you want to put the player in a separate category, and mask it out from the filter query. (By default the shape filter object matches all categories and doesnt mask out anything).

So, you want to do something like in this example:

```
>>> import pymunk
>>> s = pymunk.Space()
>>> player_b = pymunk.Body(1,1)
>>> player_c = pymunk.Circle(player_b, 10)
>>> s.add(player_b, player_c)
>>>
>>> player_c.filter = pymunk.ShapeFilter(categories=0x1)
>>> s.point_query_nearest((0,0), 0, pymunk.ShapeFilter())
PointQueryInfo(shape=<pymunk.shapes.Circle object at 0x03C07F30>, point=Vec2d(nan, nan), distance=-10.0, gradient=Vec2d(0.0, 1.0))
>>> s.point_query_nearest((0,0), 0, pymunk.ShapeFilter(mask=pymunk.ShapeFilter.ALL_MASKS ^ 0x1))
>>>
>>> other_b = pymunk.Body(1,1)
>>> other_c = pymunk.Circle(other_b, 10)
>>> s.add(other_b, other_c)
>>>
>>> s.point_query_nearest((0,0), 0, pymunk.ShapeFilter(mask=pymunk.ShapeFilter.ALL_MASKS ^ 0x1))
PointQueryInfo(shape=<pymunk.shapes.Circle object at 0x03C070F0>, point=Vec2d(nan, nan), distance=-10.0, gradient=Vec2d(0.0, 1.0))
```

There are tests in the `test_space.py` file that tests different combinations of the shape filter which might help explain how they work: https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/master/tests/test_space.py#L175